# load asp.net page partially

Tags: asp.net

I am working with ASP.net and I have two gridvew controls and some link buttons.  Now, to bind these gridviews, I have to call web services and data access.  Since I am pulling large amount of data, the page loads slow.  I am wondering if there is a way I could do partial page load, meaning that I would like show the link buttons first then show rest of gridview as data are available (to bind to gridivews).

Is there a way I can accomplish this? (Preferably, without AJAX).

Thanks.

Comment: "partial page load" usually refers to asp:UpdatePanels I think - do you mean paging (loading a few records then waiting until they click next to load a few more)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a truly AJAX-less method, you could go with the ol' trusty IFrame tags and have your gridviews be stand alone pages.  I believe the page will render around the IFrames while the IFrames themselves load.

NOTE:  I also am not advocating this a the best solution, but it may meet the intent of this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Not without AJAX. But can you define what you mean by "without AJAX"?

Have you seen PageMethods? They may do what you intend, in a way that is palatable to you.

Alternately, you may mean "without UpdatePanels" in which case, are you familiar with XMLHttpRequests? (Note: I do not intend that an XHR is the appropriate solution here, I'm probing for familiarity with the topic)

Answer (score 0):

First a couple of things, you may want to limit the data you are grabbing. If you are using a gridview this data will be stored in view state, causing huge overhead. If you are only displaying data, consider using repeater or datalists they are lighter. In any case you should be using pagination, though you may have to implement a custom pagination solution for the repeater.